# Is there a way to use a "Create New" lightning component to pre-populate a lookup once the record is created?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-action-override, lightning-components

Here's my use case:
I am creating a Quote.  We have a custom field on the Quote called Listing.  Sometimes, the listing doesn't exist and so we want them to be able to create the listing directly from the Quote page.  If we do **not** override the Listing.New button, then once I create the listing, the system returns me back to the Quote page with the listing pre-filled.

What I would like to do is override the New button with a custom lightning component.  However, once the record is saved, is there a way for me to navigate back to the Quote page AND populate the Quote.Listing field with the listing I just created?

Comment: If the child record doesn't exist and you are creating parent record then you can create the child record on the same UI in the lookup fields there last option to create new child record and once you create that it populates the same on the parent record field and finally you can save the parent record. There is no navigation.

Comment: Why would you need to create a custom component here? If `Listing` is a lookup on `Quote`, you will be always able to create a new `Listing` from the lookup field if one does not exist (it’s standard ootb behavior) and that gets associated to the `Quote`, as long as you have the create permissions on `Listing`.

Comment: @JayantDas, I need some custom functionality when they create a new listing, i.e., some dynamic field population, hiding/unhiding fields, etc.